# Is possible use a not updated column in trigger body?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, database-trigger

I'm coding a DML Trigger for insert update rows in a new table. Trigger will fired only when one single column  be updated but... Is possible use into trigger body other column outside UPDATE OF one_single_column clause?

AUDIT TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE employees_salary_history(
  user_name             VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL,
  time_stamp            date DEFAULT (sysdate),
  employee_id           NUMBER(6),
  old_salary            NUMBER(8, 2),
  new_salary            NUMBER(8, 2),
  percente_raise_salary NUMBER(8, 2));
```

DML TRIGGER:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_salary_trg
AFTER
UPDATE 
OF salary
ON employees23
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  v_user VARCHAR2(25);
BEGIN
  SELECT user
  INTO   v_user
  FROM   dual;

  INSERT INTO employees_salary_history
  VALUES(
      v_user, 
      sysdate, 
      employee_id, -- I would like add employee_id about employee that was updated, 
      :OLD.salary,
      :NEW.salary, 
      TRUNC((:NEW.salary - :OLD.salary) / :OLD.salary * 100, 3)
  );
END update_salary_trg;
```

Trigger works right when I omite "employee_id" column but I would like add employee_id as a reference about the salary updated. When I add employee_id column I receive the following error:

```
Errors: check compiler log
Errores para TRIGGER HR.UPDATE_SALARY_TRG:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- ----------------------------------
8/3      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
8/15     PL/SQL: ORA-00913: too many values
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. It's the same thing. "SQL statement ignored" "too many values"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the trigger cant reference the employee_id field. In your case New and OLD will be same . So just replace employee_id with either :OLD.employee_id or :NEW. employee_id as shown below. Hope it helps.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_salary_trg
AFTER
UPDATE 
OF salary
ON employees23
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  v_user VARCHAR2(25);
BEGIN
  SELECT user
  INTO   v_user
  FROM   dual;

  INSERT INTO employees_salary_history --employees_salary_history
  VALUES(
      v_user, 
      sysdate, 
      :NEW.employee_id, -- I would like add employee_id about employee that was updated, 
      :OLD.salary,
      :NEW.salary, 
      TRUNC((:NEW.salary - :OLD.salary) / :OLD.salary * 100, 3)
  );
END update_salary_trg;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to use any column of employees23-table in the trigger.

If the column was not changed then the values of `:old` and `:new` pseudorecords are the same.

So in your case just use `:new.employee_id`.

Next I recommend you to RTFM: [PL/SQL Triggers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS020). It also explains in the details when the pseudorecords are available and what values they hold.

Comment: Thanks for your help!